# Variable inside for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am frustrated. I am trying to find a way to get the variable called 'line' to be accessed inside of the for loop that is at the bottom of the code.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string currentmonth;
string earlydays;

//**************************************
string a3;
string a1;

int getdir (string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dp;

    struct dirent *dirp;

    if((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        std::string fname = dirp->d_name;
        if(fname.find("FIN804") != std::string::npos)
            files.push_back(fname);
    }
}

//***************************************
int main() {
    //Copy New date to be used from date database

    ifstream dailyfiledate;

    dailyfiledate.open("Databasedate.txt");

    string line;

    if (!dailyfiledate) //checks to see if file opens properly
    {
        cerr << "Error: Failed to copy the first string from Date Database.";
    }
    else
    {
        if (getline(dailyfiledate, line)) // Get line
            cout << line; // print the line.

        dailyfiledate.close(); // Remember to close the file.
    }

    string dir = string(a1);

    vector<string> files = vector<string>();

    getdir(dir,files);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < files.size();)
    {
        //cout << files[i] << endl;
        a3 = files[i];
        cout << a3 << endl;
        string b1 = a3 + line;
        cout << b1 << endl;
        remove(b1.c_str());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code first.

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable next time!  A couple of things right off the bat.  1) your `int main()` should have a return. Your compiler should have warned you about this.  2) pick an indentation style and stick with it throughout your program.

Comment: @JustinRandall Good edit. I stole your thunder with an insignificant improvement to force it to be visible.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks it was hurting my eyes had to be done

Comment: `int getdir(string dir, vector<string> &files)` promises to return an `int`, but when it succeeds, it doesn't return anything. This be [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and can cause all sorts of wondrous and mysterious things to happen.

Comment: Only problem I see in there is `a1` is empty when it's used. Strongly recommend giving variables a meaningful name so that folks coming in cold have some hope of interpreting what it's supposed to do when it's not working.

Comment: @user4581301 I think you should make that the answer. `int getdir()` not returning an integer, which the compiler should have complained about, and  more importantly `a1` being used uninitialized which makes `opendir` chance of success nil.  The code is never getting into that loop since the `vector<string> files` is empty.

Comment: @user4581301 im Sorry. I thought I explained well. The problem is that, I need the variable called "line" to work while it's inside the for loop at the bottom. For some reason.... It does not print a value Once used in the for loop. Maybe it needs a pointer or something

Comment: @user4581301 where I have "a1 + line" that part is not giving me anything for "line"...." line" is dead once inside that for loop at the bottom

Comment: @SketchFam `a1` is never initialized. And you assign that value to `dir`. When you call `getdir(dir, files)` the `opendir` will fail and therefore `files` is empty. You won't even get into that loop.  Show me where you initialize `a1` and I'll change my mind.

Comment: Sketch Fam, your post is quite clear, but the assumptions it's based on are most likely wrong. I don't believe anything prints in the loop because the program never gets into the loop. Step through the program with the debugger that came with your development environment and watch what happens. @JustinRandall I'm not making an answer because I can't figure out how Sketch isn't getting an error when the `opendir` fails.

Comment: So... Why does my question have a "-4" on it...

Comment: @TharinduLucky I'm sorry bro. I was using the ap when I posted this

Comment: @JustinRandall I am sorry, I'm a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the variable was successfully being reached inside the for loop. I guess it was an oversight on my path.

And there is absolutely no error in the code above when it's compiled.

You mo'effers really need to be more humble. Give the answer, give guidance, or don't comment at all.